# Retrieving payment URL for a Paypal Invoice

Tags: paypal

As far as I can understand the standard Invoice flow (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/invoicing/IntroInvoiceAPI/), it's supposed that the user will pay the invoice following the link in the invoice email sent by Paypal, or by using a QR code printed somewhere.

It isn't actually possibile to retrieve the payment URL contained in the email or in the QR code directly via API, so the user can be immediately redirected to payment page?

Comment: Retrieve it from where? in what context?

Comment: I mean that the unique way to pay the Invoice is by following the link in the email, but I prefer to redirect the user from my web application without requiring them to check their inbox (just how everyone is accustomed to in the standard payment workflow).

Comment: for the interested, we actually never started to use Paypal Invoice for this reason, and switched to Zoho Invoices. So far so good.

Comment: It's incredible how Paypal it's so inflexible for things like this

Comment: OH, this issue. We avoided using Paypal Invoice, and months later we switched to Stripe. Maybe after 2 years something changed?

Answer (score 1):

At this time, you can manually build the payment URL with the following template:

```
https://www.paypal.com/invoice/payerView/details/<invoice_id>
```

There are other parameters that you can pass with the URL, but they don't seem to affect the ability of someone paying the invoice.