# Paypal REST API Invoice : get show invoice URL

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have been able to create and send an invoice through the new PayPal REST API PHP SDK. I receive the invoice email in my sandbox.

What I would like to have is the URL that is given in the email to see the invoice. I tried the `getUri` method, but it just returns `null`.

Is there a way to do this?

***UPDATE***

For the moment, the workaround I found is to create manually the invoice link like this:

**For sandbox:**
`https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi_bin/webscr?cmd=_pay-inv&id=[INVOICE_ID]`

Comment: I saw this question but this is for the Classic API. I am using the new one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976606/retrieving-payment-url-for-a-paypal-invoice